# How to read PHP function into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function snippets which calculate the bi-monthly payment schedule. I need to be able to ready the values as individual array element to be inserted into MYSQL database. How do I achieve this?

```
function calculatePaymentSchedule($d1, $months){
    $date = new DateTime($d1);

    // call second function to add the months
    $newDate = $date->add(addMonths($months, $date));

    //formats final date to Y-m-d form
    $dateReturned = $newDate->format('Y-m-d'); 

    return $dateReturned;
}

$startDate = '2018-5-15'; 
$duration = 12;
$paymentCount = $duration + 2;

for($i =0; $i < $paymentCount; $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0 && $i != 0){
        $final = calculatePaymentSchedule($startDate, $i);
        echo $final.'<br>';
    }
}
```

**current state output:**

```
2018-07-15
2018-09-15
2018-11-15
2019-01-15
2019-03-15
2019-05-15
```

Comment: Use `$final[] = calculatePaymentSchedule($startDate, $i);` so you fill the `$final` array with the individual results and reference the array elements for inserts into your database.

Comment: Already did that. First element resulted in 2018-07-15
2018-07-15
2018-07-15
2018-07-15
2018-07-15
2018-07-15  instead of 2018-07-15.

Answer (score 1):

initalize array at top:

```
all_dates = array();
```

in for loop :

```
$final = calculatePaymentSchedule($startDate, $i);
array_push($all_dates, $final);
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Your solution is already implemented; it worked. You deserve +1

Comment: I'm glad i cloud help!